# How to remove a ChangeListener in Android / libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

How to remove a Changelistener in Libgdx / Android. I hope you can help.

```
public void addlistenerStartscreen(final TextButton button){
    button.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
            stage.clear();
            //Remove Listener from button
            showGame();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

API is defined [here](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Actor.html#removeListener-com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.EventListener-)

And it looks like this:

```
public boolean removeListener(EventListener listener)
```

(Actor's API)

Comment: i know this but i dont defined the ChangeListener. If i ride button.removeListener(Changelistener) it's false

Comment: Dude, check out [ChangeLIstener's API too](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/utils/ChangeListener.html). It implements EventListener.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to remove your listener without reference to it. So the simplest modification to your code should look so:

```
ChangeListener myChangeListener;

button.addListener(myChangeListener = new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
            stage.clear();

            //Remove Listener from button
            button.removeListener(myChangeListener);

            showGame();
        }
    });
```

There is another way to remove all listeners from any Actor, but **this code will very likely broke native behavior of some actors** (e.g, Button, it uses internal click listener to manage pressed state). But I leave it up to you anyway, it may be useful for your custom actors.

```
static void removeAllListeners(Actor actor) {
        Array<EventListener> listeners = new Array<>(actor.getListeners());
        for (EventListener listener : listeners) {
            actor.removeListener(listener);
        }
    }
```